# Troubleshoot ssh -X a lot less responsive than VNC

Tags: ssh, vnc, bandwidth

I need to work on a GUI on a remote Linux (CentOs) server (I measured with `iperf` a ~8Mbits/sec connection between these two machines). I always used `ssh -X` instead of VNC for this since:

- I need to open only one window so I like to have it as a window as if I opened this program on my computer
- I can use my SSH key for this
- I want the software to adapt to the size of my desktop, not the virtual VNC desktop (though I guess there are options for that with VNC)

But here what appears is that using my GUI with VNC is a lot faster than with SSH -X, I see a lot more quickly the changes in the GUI when I use it so I'm kind of obliged to use it.

It seems to me that VNC just sends a compressed image of the part of the screen that changes which is a lot faster than SSH that need to send all informations to me.

For instance with ssh -X it takes 5 to 10 seconds to react to me clicking to the 'File' menu of Firefox and display it. With VNC there is no visible delay.

So my question are:

- Is VNC expected to be a lot faster than ssh -X?
- If not, how can I troubleshoot to see why ssh -X is so slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, X11 is network transparent, so it *can* be used over the network. However, X11 is also a *very* chatty protocol, meaning that it takes often hundreds of request/response cycles to display a single window. That is why X11 over network is usually only used locally, even 1GBit/s makes a big difference compared to a 100Mbit/s connection.

There are several ways around that, VNC is the one you have mentioned, [NoMachine's NX](http://www.nomachine.com/) is the other one - it optimizes the X11 protocol by caching, proxying and compression and can provide near-realtime performance even over slow links like ISDN. The free version of it is limited.
There are free implementations of the core NX protocol (since it's open source) like [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) (server side) and [OpenNX](http://opennx.net/) (client side), but both are not very actively developed and have some bugs which make them less than ideal for everyday use.